# How can i add more than 10 buttons on a navigationbar in iphone application development?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

In my application I have to add 8 buttons on a navigation bar..So it's very much normal that these button should be in a view and there should be one previous and next button. When i will press the next button then using animation it will show the next buttons whose are out of the view and same as for previous button.

For Details:

1. UINavigation Bar -> leftBaritem[previous button] + view + rightBaritem[next button];
2. view will contain 8 buttons. If I explain again then it should be look like this:

> Previous + | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H + next

when I will press

> next

then it will show like this:

> previous + | B | C | D | E | F | G | H + next

like this for

> previous

button.

EDIT:

In this picture there are three button in a view but i have six button to add on the view "Dashbord , order , Product". Now when i will press ">" or "<" or left/right bar items then it will show the buttons of the nav bar which are out of the view.

[image]

Comment: A navigation bar, really?  I'd love to see a screenshot of the UI you're trying to come up with.  It sounds potentially confusing to the user. Why not use a page controller?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it might help you get started: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jsscrollabletabbar

Comment: @chris yes i need such kind of bar..but i dont know how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem slightly different way....

In `viewDidLoad` I have take a `scrollView` and called my function

```
menuScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
menuScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
menuScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
menuScrollView.bounces = TRUE;


[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(70.0, 30.0) withOffset:20.0f noOfButtons:7];
```

Then in my `function` i have created my menu `buttons` which will be look like buttons on a `navigation bar`

```
-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

NSLog(@"inserting into the function for menu bar button creation"); 
for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(mybuttons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if(i==0){
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dashboard"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==1){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==2){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==3){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Customers"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==4){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==5){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Site Analysis"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==6){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Store Settings"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    else if(i==7){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CMS Settings"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 8.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0;//half of the width
    //button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    button.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    button.layer.borderWidth=0.0f;
    button.tag=i;
    [menuScrollView addSubview:button];
}
menuScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);
[self.view addSubview:menuScrollView];

}
```

and it solves...Happy Coding... :))

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the wrong thing.  You should not be trying to force 8 buttons into a navigation bar.

You need to rethink your interface.  Two reasonable approaches come to mind:

- Use a tab bar.  A tab bar has support for handling more options than will fit on the screen.  For example, the built-in Music app has 10 tabs.
- Put your eight buttons in a full-screen view under a navigation controller.  When the user clicks one, push the appropriate view for that button.  The user can pop back (using the navigation controller's normal back button support) to pick a different button.

Comment: chris has given me this url and i want such kind of bar but i want to know how can i do that? http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jsscrollabletabbar